# threeJS / threeCSG - stray edges on coplanar faces after threeCSG boolean functions when using EdgesGeometry

Tags: 3d, three.js, csg, threecsg

I am using EdgesGeometry to show the outer edges of the mesh as so : EdgesGeometry( geometry, thresholdAngle ).

This normally works as expected but after a using threeCSG to either 'subtract' or 'union' and then generating the EdgesGeometry on the resulting mesh I get various stray edges appear on coplanar faces, even if I increase the 'thresholdAngle' to say '180 degrees', they remain.

This is what happens -
[image]

Here's my code:
(a & b are the meshes of the box geometry)

```
a_ = new ThreeBSP( a );
b_ = new ThreeBSP( b );

c_ = a_.subtract(b_);
c = c_.toMesh(mat_cube);

scene.add( c );

edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( c.geometry, 5 )
line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, mat_line )
scene.add( line )
```

anyone got any ideas? 
thanks

**UPDATE**

below is what it looks like with 'WireframeGeometry'...
[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but if you want to know where those edges come from, you can apply wireframe to your mesh `c` and see its structure.

Comment: I've added that above. Doesn't really seem to explain why some of these lines are remaining though when using 'EdgesGeometry'

Comment: I mean to use `.wireframe: true` of the mesh's material to see what happens inside.

Comment: sure, yeah that shows the same mesh as what shows with 'EdgesGeometry', and there's nothing extra going on behind the visible faces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing unexpected "edges" when rendering with `EdgesGeometry`.

The cause is an artifact of the output of `threeCSG`.

The long edge of the large triangle is *coincident* with edges of three smaller triangles -- *coincident*, but not *shared*.

That means, the long edge is not shared at all. Nor are the three short edges.

Edges that are not shared are rendered by EdgesGeometry.

three.js r.87

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think I understand but am still puzzled on how to deal with this, it seems as if it should be fixable or is this just a flaw with the threeCSG system...?

Comment: To fix it you would have to replace the big triangle with three smaller triangles that use the vertices on the long edge. Note the same problem is occurring around the rectangular indentation.

Comment: ok.. so firstly I need to come up with a way of identifying those larger faces in the geometry, then i need come up with a way replacing them with the correct faces.. is that right? I'll give it a go i guess... Unless someone has already done something like this?

Comment: three.js is a rendering engine, not a modeling tool. Build or edit your model outside of three.js and import it.